# Characterization of initial locally injective maps.

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Is an initial and locally injective map between topological spaces an embedding? By initial I mean the topology of the domain is the initial topology. It seems easy to prove that such a map is a local embedding, but I fail to prove it is injective. On the other hand I can't find a counterexample to prove that the assertion is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:X\to Y$ be initial and not injective. There are $x_0,x_1\in X$, $x_0\ne x_1$ such that $f(x_0)=f(x_1)=y$. Let $U$ be any open nbhd of $x_0$; then $U=f^{-1}[V]$ for some open nbhd $V$ of $y$, so $x_1\in U$. Thus, $f$ is not injective on any nbhd of $x_0$ and hence is not locally injective.

Comment: Thanks, that was fast!

Comment: @Arpegio: You’re welcome.